# How do you use Set with Table View?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, set

I want to iterate through `Set` and display them in a table, but I'm getting an error that says:

> Fatal error: Invalid index

Following is my code:

```swift
@NSManaged public var progress: Set<Progress>

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return progress.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = progress[progress.index(progress.startIndex, offsetBy: indexPath.row)].comment
    return cell
}
```

Comment: `let array = Array(progress)`

Comment: As others have pointed out, a Swift `Set` type is unordered. You can't use a set as a data source for a table view. You need to convert your Set to an array or other ordered collection. (The old Objective-C interface includes the `NSOrderedSet` class, but I don't recommend using it in new Swift code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `indexPath.row` as index in the `Array` after converting the `Set<Progress>` to `Array<Progress>` using the `Array(Set)` initializer.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = Array(progress)[indexPath.row].comment
```

Better Approach: Using the `Array(Set)` initializer in `cellForRowAt` each time is less efficient, also the order of elements cannot be guaranteed. It would be better to do it just once right after the `progress: Set<Progress>` is initialized.

```
var progressArray: [Progress] // set this right after `progress` is set
```

Then in `cellForRowAt`:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = progressArray[indexPath.row].comment
```

Comment: That would create an array from the (unordered!) set on each invocation of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` – not very efficient. And are you sure that the order in the array is always the same?

Comment: Could do the array conversion once in `viewDidLoad`. Which would avoid the order confusion I guess.

Answer (score 4):

A `Set` is unordered. `Sort` the set – for example by `date` – to get an array in a specific order and use this as data source array

```
var progresses = [Progress]() 

...   

progresses = progress.sorted{$0.date < $1.date}
```

Comment: I get an error saying `Cannot call value of non-function type '[Set<Progress>]'`

Comment: Error where, in which line?